# How do I select a tab and set content of the tabpanel in JavaScript

Tags: tabs, xul, tabpanel

I'm stuck at this: I've created tabs and corresponding tabpanels. By default, I've hidden the tabs. To make a tab visible, I use this JavaScript line:

```js
document.getElementById("tab-id").setAttribute("selected", true);
```

However, the content of the corresponding `tabpanel` does not update as I expected. I've tried using this:

```js
document.getElementById("tabbox-id").selectedPanel = "tabpanel-id";
```

But nothing is happening; the content of the `tabpanel` is not updated.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selected` attribute is set internally, it is merely an indicator that selection changed - changing it won't actually change selection. What you most likely want to do is this:

```js
var tabpanel = document.getElementById("tabpanel-id");
document.getElementById("tabbox-id").selectedPanel = tabpanel;
```

Note that `selectedPanel` is the panel and not its ID. Alternatively you could also use `selectedIndex`:

```js
document.getElementById("tabbox-id").selectedIndex = 1;
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbox)

Comment: I've used the first option. Works like a charm. Thanks.